# Recently installed Miktex 2.9 running slow. How to fix it?

Tags: miktex

I've recently installed WinEdt 7.0 and Miktex 2.9 on a new computer. But now when I attempt to compile a latex file, there is a delay of about 20 seconds before the compilation process begins (and the log file appears). The compilation process itself seems to be reasonably fast.

The first thing to appear (before the delay in question) is

```
Command Line: latex.exe--src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "name-of-file.tex"  
Startup folder:C:\Latex files
```

then (after I've finished my espresso)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1-40.13 (MikTeX 2.9)...
```

followed by the rest of the log file.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that something is left on a network folder and each time TeX tries to reach to it?

Comment: @percusse: It's possible, I guess. How can I check?

Comment: Compile from the command line to decide if the problem is with miktex or with winedt.

Comment: Addition to @UlrikeFischer's suggestion add the option `–recorder` to see the absolute paths of the files used.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: The delay is a bit shorter (12 seconds or so) when the file is compiled from the command line. But still not ideal.

Comment: @Shane: So the problem is with miktex. Where are the roots? Most importantly where is the root with the formats and FNDB (called UserData and/or CommonData in miktex settings).

Comment: @ShaneORourke: Look at [this answer](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28257577) from Christian Schenk: First run after an update takes longer because it updates its data base. May be this is what happens.